# Report Viewing in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am up for making a software in vb which uses MSACCESS database and has to view some reports. This includes getting loads of information from different tables in the database and arranging  them in order.

I want to format the report using tables and text. Is there any way to use tables as in HTML.

I mean is there a way such that we can use HTML Tables (or anything like that) in VB.NET?

***PS: I am not a pro VB programmer. So, I don't know the thing***

**FORMAT I WANT TO VIEW:**

Name: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Tag: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

[table start]

[table data]

[table end]

Other Info:

*The table is a standard table with merged row and columns.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use Microsoft Report (RDLC) to Make Custom Reports of your database.

1. Add a report and a dataset from Project Menu
2. Design rdlc as you wish
3. Add a Tablix to your rdlc and set the dataset as datasource
4. Add a reportviewer to your form and set the designed local report
5. Pass your customized data to dataset and refresh your report

Through this, you can print and export in excel and pdf formats.
Rdlc has some built in html structure, I dont think you can edit it.

OR

You can use a print document on your own and provide HTML code as string content directly. It will render them in its own.

I prefer using RDLC, simple and best. :)
All the best...

EDIT:
Name and Tag can be passed to report as 'reportParameters'
RDLC does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vb data grid control , follow the below link

http://www.vbtutor.net/lesson26.html

**Edit**

The above is for vb and not for vb.net, if you are looking for vb.net try datagrid components or generate HTML and load them using a browser control inside your windows app

Comment: Yeah! you mean file handling? or there is another way to create HTML

Comment: You can design your form to be that way or you really don't need create a HTML File you can create the content and push to browser object on the fly , either by using temp file or directly by writing into the document

Answer (score 1):

You can use RDLC or Crystal Report

- [Walkthrough: Using a Database Data Source with the ReportViewer Windows Forms Control in Local Processing Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251724%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Using a Database Data Source with the ReportViewer Web Forms Control in Local Processing Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252123%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)